# How to deserialize json with json-lenses

Tags: json, scala

What is the best practice to deserialize JSON to a Scala case class using json-lenses?

some.json :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Alice"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Bob"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Chris"
  }
]
```

some case class :

```
case class Foo(id: Long, name: String)
```

What's best way to convert the json in *some.json* to `List[Foo]` ?

Answer (score 0):

json-lenses supports [spray-json](https://github.com/spray/spray-json) and with spray-json you could do:

```
import spray.json._

case class Foo(id: Long, name: String)

object JsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val FooFormat = jsonFormat2(Foo)
}

import JsonProtocol._
val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("some.json")
val json = try source.mkString.parseJson finally source.close()

json.convertTo[List[Foo]]
// List[Foo] = List(Foo(1,Alice), Foo(2,Bob), Foo(3,Chris))
```